# How to use flash.filesystem.FileStream

Tags: apache-flex, filestream

Will

How to use `flash.filesystem.FileStream` ?

`FileStream.as` file Where?

Answer (score 6):

The class [flash.filesystem.FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) is only available in Adobe AIR. It is not available in Flash Player in the browser. Furthermore, there is no FileStream.as available to read the source code because it is compiled into the runtime and probably written in a lower-level language like C++.

If you want to open a file in Flash Player in the browser, you should use [flash.net.FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) and call the `browse()` method to display a file dialog. Once the user selects a file, you'll receive `Event.SELECT` and you can call the `load()` method to get a ByteArray of data.

If you are targeting Adobe AIR, then the document [Reading and writing files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc2.html) should provide you with all the information you need.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans of porting this to web Flash Player?

Comment: You can use browse() and load() to open files, and save() to save them, with the FileReference class in Flash Player on the web.

Comment: @joshtynjala: Can I use FileStream class in a SWC Flex Library called in a AIR project?

Comment: As long as you target AIR when you compile the SWC file, you can use FileStream and any other AIR classes. I think the Flex SDK includes amxmlc and acompc executables to compile for AIR.

Answer (score 0):

This is an AIR only class, so you have to be compiling to the AIR runtime to get it to work.