# Random access (or at least incremental) write to file from a browser-hosted app

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight, applet, randomaccessfile

I am designing an application, which is intended to be run in a browser. This application is generating some data, which is then to be saved to a file. In certain cases amount of this data could exceed amount of available RAM, so we can't wait until all data is created and only then write it to disk at once.

I need a random access or (at least) an incremental (i.e., appending) write to file from a browser-based application.

In my research I've found following:

1. [HTML5 FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/): Gives us exactly what we want, but as for current moment is only available in webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Opera). As [this document](http://caniuse.com/filesystem) states, Firefox is not planning to implement it in nearest versions, no information about IE11 or Safari 7 is available.
2. All js-based implementations of file saving procedure I've found do not support this (expectedly).
3. Flash has a class [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) but it is [not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073924/664178) in an in-browser Flash player.
4. Silverlight also has a [FileStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but an application using it needs to be an *elevated-trust application*. Browser-based Silverlight applications can only be elevated-trust applications if it is stated so [in the Windows registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This is obviously not an option for a web application. Furthermore, this is probably not possible to do on Mac OS.

Other options that I see here are ActiveX and Java.

So, am I missing something with js, Flash or Silverlight? Is it possible to do with ActiveX or Java? Are there any other options?

Comment: *"Is it possible to do with ActiveX or Java?"*  It is possible using a Java applet, presuming you can get the browser to launch the applet.  That last part recently became a lot tougher after security bugs prompted Oracle to tighten the security regime used to launch applets.

Comment: I think in Silverlight you could save it to disk with a FileStream if you save to isolated storage.  This is specific to the user and application, though.  Do other users need to be able to read the file?

Comment: @john_cat it needs to be a normal file, which can later be opened in other applications, so isolated storage is not an option, sadly.

Comment: What about saving the file on the server, and using the web server to serve it up when you need to open it in another application?

Comment: @john_cat as I said in the original post, the problem appears when the data could not fit in the RAM, i.e., more than 8Gb for more or less modern computers. Uploading and them downloading 8 or more Gb is not really a viable workaround :)

Comment: Fair point.  Do you really need all of it at once, or could you fetch the data paged as required?

Comment: @john_cat yeah, all at once. But, actually, I think I might be onto something with the isolated storage idea you suggested. I think (need to try it), I can do the incremental write to the file in the isolated storage, then open it for reading, open a file in the real filesystem for writing and pass the filestream of the isolated file to the filewriter (or whatever the class is called)...

Comment: I don't understand that.  If you can open a file in the file system for writing at all, surely the isolated storage is an unnecessary step.  If you're stuck in the sandbox, you can't open a file from the file system at all, regardless of how you're trying to write to it.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @john_cat you can initiate a File save dialog and then get a permission to write the file specified by the user. The problem is that you are rather limited in the ways to actually write data to that file afterwards.