# How does fileStream work in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, memory, air, buffer, filestream

I am working on a project which reads large csv files in adobe AIR. I was successful in doing that by reading files [line by line](http://sangupta.com/tech/actionscript-read-text-file-line-by.html).

To fully understand the file reading i need to know how the filestream in flex works.

1. Where is the buffer of the filestream stored? Does it take up space
   in the RAM? When i debug my application on opening a 450MB csv file
   and look at the bytesAvailable property of the native fileStream it
   shows 450MB. But the application does not take up more than 70MB on
   memory(task manager).
2. Also will the application crash if i try to open a really large file
       say 3GB ?(my RAM is 4GB and i am running on 64bit Windows 7 OS)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073924/5189158) suggests that the fileStream could have been implemented in C++. Can this be true?

From what i researched so far i came to know that filestream opens a connection to the given file and copies the content of the file into an [internal buffer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dac.html).

I cannot come up with any other additional information. The adobe documentation for fileStream shows how to use it and gives nothing on the lines of what i am looking for.

Any information regardin gthis would be truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ..i think : [How do I use fileStream without reading the file into memory?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3428563#3428563) 
 You can use c or c++ as 'native process' also, if you have knowledge it can be easier :) 
 *edit - filestream loads data in to RAM, do not close the fileStream when you check it. 'out of memory'or something similar appears if RAM is not enough

Comment: I didnt close the stream when i checked the memory. I was surprised on such a low memory consumption by the app and thats why i posted the question.

Comment: what does native process have to do with any of this. are you suggesting that flex starts a  'C' nativeprocess when using filestream? (that would be absurd)

Comment: no, i suggest to use native process instead filestream. You can pass params to 'c' code -> search for new lines -> and get desired result as byte array back. I have no idea why your memory is so low ...i`ve made a couple of tests with the same result

Comment: oh.. but i have no problem in reading the file using filestream. i just wanted to know how it works. and what do you mean same result? low memory?